# What is the group nvidia-persistenced

Tags: nvidia, 15.04

Since I use the PPA [`ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) I have the group `nvidia-persistenced` in my system. Why this group is needed?

```
% cat /etc/group | grep nvidia
nvidia-persistenced:x:154:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `nvidia-persistenced` utility is used to enable persistent software state in the NVIDIA driver. When persistence mode is enabled, the daemon prevents the driver from releasing device state when the device is not in use. This can improve the startup time of new clients in this scenario.
>
> The daemon does not require root privileges to run, and may safely be run as an unprivileged user, given that its runtime directory, `/var/run/nvidia-persistenced`, is created for and owned by that user prior to starting the daemon. `nvidia-persistenced` also requires read and write access to the NVIDIA character device files. If the permissions of the device files have been altered through any of the `NVreg_DeviceFileUID`, `NVreg_DeviceFile_GID`, or `NVreg_DeviceFileMode` NVIDIA kernel module options, `nvidia-persistenced` will need to run as a suitable user.

So this group is created to handle specific permissions for this daemon. E. g. `/var/run/nvidia-persistenced` is owned by `nvidia-persistenced`.

[Source](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man1/alt-nvidia-331-updates-persistenced.1.html)

And this user and group is not specific to the PPA. It is created for Nvidia drivers installed from Ubuntu repositories as well.